# How to add a new peer in the existing quorum network without using geth console?

Tags: ethereum, raft, quorum

I am trying to test the addition of new node in the existing quorum network. Is there any other way to do it without going to geth console and executing admin.addPeer().

Is there any API present where I can call and add the new peer so that it can synchronize accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to do it. I have written a shell script which goes to geth console and add a peer and returns a raftID in response.